# How to apply session on JSP page without using <% page session =""%>

Tags: jsp, session

Is it possible to use existing session in jsp without using  `<% page session="false"%>`?

Are there any alternatives for it?

Since our project has 200 jsp's, it is not easy to write that code for each and every jsp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The servlet spec allows you to automatically import a jsp for a set of pages using jsp property groups.

You can add session="false" in the top.jsp so that it will be applied to all jsps

```
<jsp-property-group>
  <description>JSP configuration</description>
  <url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern>
  <include-prelude>/includes/top.jsp</include-prelude>
</jsp-property-group>
```